# How to check the containers running on a pod in kubernettes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am able to get a list of all pods running on a kubernetes cluster using:

```
kubectl get pods
```

How do I get all the containers running on a particular pod?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `describe` command:

```
kubectl describe pod [podname]
```

That will specify which containers are in the pod, along with other information.

Comment: If this does not work (it tells you that podname does not exists), you  need to add the namespace. `kubectl describe pod PODNAME -n NAMESPACE`

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
kubectl describe pod pod_name
```

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl describe pod podname`, if you would like get the image name of the container in the pod then `kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" -l key=value`.